# Qt Creator Line edit and button size for hi-dpi and low dpi system

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm have to re-layout a very complicated UI because we've discovered it's essentially unusable on high dpi systems. This is due to the fact that we have used fixed sizes on just about everything in order to get the layout design we want in Qt Creator.

My Question is, how can I size objects (line edits, buttons, spin boxes, etc etc etc) such that they maintain relative sizes to each other to maintain the desired layout?

For example:

[image: Example Layout with fixed pixel sized objects]

This renderd exactly as it looks on a 1080p screen but it's completely unreadable on a windows tablet with a 2736 x 1824 resolution.

[image: Rendered Layout on Hi-DPI]

So how do I fix this? If I remove the absolute pixel size values, all those buttons and line edits expand horizontally out of control and nearly tripple the width of the widget. Not only is this completely unnecessary for the data they will contain, it ruins the UI.

I have tried layouts. Layouts don't stop these objects from expanding. There appears to be some hidden minimum size that is set arbitrarily far too large for my purposes.

I have looked over the Qt Creator resources I can find. Lots of patting themselves on the back for supporting hi-dpi, nothing about how to design for this to achieve a consistent look across devices with different resolutions.

Comment: What style did you use? Test using `qApp->setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: give that this is all in Qt Creator, where do I put that code? And what will this give me?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Qt?

Qt 5.6 introduce High Dpi Support and adjust all the views by the system scale factor. Take a look to the [HDPI Displys Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html). Basically, add this line to your main function before set up your applicatio to enable the automatic scale:

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
......
```

Comment: I am using Qt 5.4, and unfortunately the decision to upgrade is beyond my pay-grade. If we do upgrade, thank you, I'll certainly use that.